# Filter list equals to parameter

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a List of object where there is an attribute of boolean `isEnabled`. 
I want to use streams to filter the list based on the parameter of a method.

```
List<Object> myMethod(boolean enabled) {
    List<Object> myObjects = getObjectsFromDB();

    // I want to filter myObjects to return only objects
    // where enabled == object.isEnabled
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: isEnabled does not belong to Object class methods, what is the end class of object, where you are going to call isEnabled?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on end-class you are going to use it should be something like this:

```
List<YourClass> filtered = myObjects.stream()
                           .map(o -> (YourClass)o)
                           .filter(o -> enabled == o.isEnabled())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

alternatively

```
List<Object> filtered = myObjects.stream()
                           .filter(o -> enabled == ((YourClass)o).isEnabled())
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I think OP wanted all objects where `object.isEnabled() == enabled`, where `enabled` is a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can do cast the objects in the class and check the attribute

```
List<Object> myMethod() {
    List<Object> myObjects = getObjectsFromDB();
    List<Object> ret = myObjects.stream()
          .filter(x -> ((MyClass)x).isEnabled()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```